# Cómo animar una imagen y luego reproducir un video con jQuery o CSS3

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estoy realizando una página web. Quisiera que al iniciar la página aparezca el logo de la página durante 2 segundos y luego se mueva a una esquina de la pantalla (esquina superior izquierda) y luego de eso, agregar el atributo autoload al video y empezar a reproducirlo.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#chivatera_logo").animate({
   top:2%,
   left:2%;
   max-width:10%,
  },500, function(){
   $('.videos_fondos').attr('autoplay');
   $('.videos_fondos').play();
  });
});

$(document).on("mouseover", ".enlaces_paginas", function(e){
 var id=$(this).attr("id");
 if (id=="embarcadero") {
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/02.mp4'),500);
 }else if(id=="origen"){
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/03.mp4'),500);
 }else if(id=="plaza"){
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/04.mp4'),500);
 }else if(id=="ferrocarril"){
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/05.mp4'),500);
 }else if(id=="galeria"){
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/06.mp4'),500);
 }else if(id=="equipo"){
  setInterval($(".videos_fondos").attr('src', './videos/07.mp4'),500);
 }
});
```

```css
#chivatera_logo{
 max-width:50%;
 position:absolute;
 left:23%;
 top:18%;
}

.videos_fondos{
 position:fixed;

 min-width:100%;
 min-height:80%;

 top:50%;
 left:50%;

 transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

 z-index:-10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <a href=""><img src="./imagenes/chivatera_logo.png" id="chivatera_logo"></a>
 <video src="./videos/01.mp4" loop class="videos_fondos" muted></video>
</div>
```

Este es el código con el que lo estoy intentando. Por favor, si alguien me pudiera ayudar, lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: ya has intentado utilizar funciones asíncronas de Jquery?

Comment: En realidad, no. ¿Cómo es eso?

Comment: Bueno, no se si sea específicamente lo que buscas pero una función asíncrona permite ejecutar una función y luego otro sin necesidad de activar un botón o un clic en algo, lo que permitiría, hacer lo que quieres, es decir en el **Jquery** y le digo que primero quiero la función animación del logo, y después quiero que se ejecute la función de mover a la esquina, y luego la función reproducir vídeo.

Comment: Eso es lo que intento hacer, pero el primer problema, es que la animación no se realiza. Y si no se realiza, tampoco me modifica el video.

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto te ayude:

```
function Logo() {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve('Resuelta');
            }, 2000);
          });
        }

        async function Animacion() {
          console.log('Lamar a la otra función');
    //Espera Que primero se resulva la función logo
          var result = await Logo();
          console.log(result);
        }

        asyncCall();
```

Esto debería ayudar a hacer lo que quieres, si no funciona tú animación quizá sea un error en esta, solo faltaría que agregaras la función Vídeo, haciendo lo que tu quieres.

Saludos

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionar. No entiendo qué ocurre.

Comment: ¿Que error muestra la consola?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: asyncCall is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):22)
    at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: asyncCall is not defined ReferenceError: asyncCall is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/chivatera/:22:4)
    at e (http://localhost/chivatera/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:29453)
    at t (http://localhost/chivatera/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:29755) undefined

Comment: Y este también.

Comment: Elimina el llamado de    **asyncCall();** Y pon **Logo()**